# SimpleJDBC call for stored procedure in ORACLE database

Tags: java, stored-procedures

I am trying to implement code which will have resultset using simpljdbccall or jdbccall or namedtemplatejdbc

Code will use my stored procedure which is database proc having input parameter and an REF cursor.

I did not found any code which will help me to extract cursor as output to have all multiple rows details in in my resultset using JDBC

DATABASE PROCEDURE

```
BOOKING_PG.get_infant_info_pr(

    c_booking_id                      IN T_BOOKED_INFANT_INFO.BOOKING_ID%TYPE,
    c_booked_infant_details           OUT    booked_infant_details
)
  OPEN c_booked_infant_details  FOR
  SELECT
  BOOKING_ID                      c_booking_id,
  BOOKED_INFANT_INFO_ID             c_booked_infant_info_id,
  BOOKED_ADULT_PAX_INFO_ID      c_booked_adult_pax_info_id,

  FROM  T_BOOKED_INFANT_INFO T
  WHERE T.BOOKING_ID = c_booking_id
  and T.STATUS_ID = 1;
```

JAVA Code

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource2)
                .withCatalogName("BOOKING_PG")
                .withProcedureName("get_infant_info_pr")
                .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
                .returningResultSet("rs1", new ParameterizedRowMapper() {
                    @Override
                    public Object[] mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        return new Object[]{rowNum, rs.getLong("c_booking_id"), rs.getLong(c_booked_infant_info_id) , rs.getLong(c_booked_adult_pax_info_id)};
                        }
                });
        SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue(C_BOOKING_ID, bookingId);

        Map<String, Object> res = call.execute(in);

        List<Object[]> l1 = (List<Object[]>)res.get("rs1");
```

It is throwing SQL error

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call EURONOVA.BOOKING_PG.GET_INFANT_INFO_PR(?)}]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_INFANT_INFO_PR'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

I am not sure if there is something wrong in the code or we have to follow some different way to get resultset in simplejdbc call

Can someone please help me in this topic?

Comment: Why don't you just copy this select from the procedure and paste into your java code?

Comment: Actually we can use that select queries , but there will be regular changes in the column_name and for each change database can be easily deployed.

But Java changes are deployed once in 3 months. So we dont use select query on java side

Comment: Try use views for select if you can't try [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973284/get-resultset-from-stored-procedure-in-oracle-from-java) it must works

Answer (score 0):

First create a class having similar data type and names which your cursor returns.
In your case create a class named BookedInfantDetails.java

```
public class BookedInfantDetails{

   private int bookingId;
   private int bookedInfantinfoId;
   private int bookedadultpaxinfoid;

   public int getBookingId() {
       return bookingId;
   }

   public void setBookingId(int bookingId) {
       this.bookingId = bookingId;
   }

   public int getBookedInfantinfoId() {
       return bookedInfantinfoId;
   }

   public void setBookedInfantinfoId(int bookedInfantinfoId) {
       this.bookedInfantinfoId = bookedInfantinfoId;
   }

   public int getBookedadultpaxinfoid() {
       return bookedadultpaxinfoid;
   }

   public void setBookedadultpaxinfoid(int bookedadultpaxinfoid) {
       this.bookedadultpaxinfoid = bookedadultpaxinfoid;
   }
```

}

Now declare in and out parameters in the jdbccall and map the ref cursor to the class using beanproperty rowmapper.

```
SimpleJdbcCall call = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource2)
            .withCatalogName("BOOKING_PG")
            .withProcedureName("get_infant_info_pr")
            .withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess()
            .declareParameters(new SqlParameter("c_booking_id", OracleTypes.Integer),
             new SqlParameter("c_booked_infant_details", OracleTypes.CURSOR),
            .returningResultSet("c_booked_infant_details", 
             BeanPropertyRowMapper.newInstance(BookedInfantDetails.class));

    SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource()
            .addValue(C_BOOKING_ID, bookingId);

    Map<String, Object> res = call.execute(in);

    List<BookedInfantDetails> l1=
    (List<BookedInfantDetails>)res.get("c_booked_infant_details");
```

Find Our more details on spring docs....
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/old-docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#orcl.datatypes.ref_cur